# Automorphic representation of weight 3 eigenforms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, k3-surfaces

Let $f$ be a weight 3 eigenform with rational Fourier coefficients. As shown by Elkies and Schutt, $f$ is associated to a singular K3 surface over $\mathbb{Q}$. A construction of Shioda and Inose relates each such surface with a pair $(E_1,E_2)$ of isogenous CM-elliptic curves.

Denote by $\pi_f$ the automorphic representation corresponding to $f$, and by $\pi_E$ the automorphic representation corresponding to either one of the two $E_i$.

> 1. Is it true that $\pi_f$ is obtained from $\pi_E$ by a quadratic base change?

Now assume $f$ is a weight 3 eigenform with non-rational Fourier coefficients. Assuming the previous speculation is true:

> 2. Can one expect $\pi_f$ to be related to the automorphic representations attached to a weight 2 cusp form, as above?

Comment: If you look at the Galois representations, the Galois representation associated to $f$ will be a summand of the symmetric square of the Galois representation associated to $\pi_E$. This isn't a base change operation on the Galois side and so should correspond to automorphic base change. Rather, it's something like you base change up to a quadratic field, obtaining an Eisenstein series of two characters, square each character, form the Eisenstein series, and base change down.

Comment: I seem to get that $a_p(f)=a_p(E)^2-2p$ for all primes $p$ that split in the quadratic imaginary field $f$ has CM by. This led me to believe that there may be a base change involved. Is that the correct relationship between the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $E$?

Comment: Sounds right to me. That relationship would only look like base change if it occurred at inert primes, not split primes.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. One more question: is there a relationship between the level $N_f$ of $f$ and the conductor $N_E$ of $E$? For instance, if $f$ is one one of the two forms at level 15 with integer coefficients, I'm not really sure how to find the corresponding $E$.

Comment: It seems to me that one is free to quadratic twist $E$ and that after doing so one can ensure it is never ramified at a prime that $f$ is not ramified at.  However, it can be more ramified at a given prime of ramification. In fact, being a CM elliptic curve it should never have $p$ dividing the conductor but not $p^2$ as that implies multiplicative reduction. So I would start looking at modular forms of weight $2$ and conductor $3^2 5^2$.

Comment: (Except not quite that since elliptic curves with CM by $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$ won't live over $\mathbb Q$.)